# Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined - nestjs with typeorm and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I'm setting up a simple API using nestjs with typeorm and mongodb. However when I make a simple http request I get the following error

`[Nest] 8852   - 09/28/2021, 6:06:03 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined +4874934ms TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined at FindCursor.cursor.toArray (C:\Users\admin\Documents\projects\shoplist\api\node_modules\typeorm\entity-manager\MongoEntityManager.js:669:37) at MongoEntityManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Documents\projects\shoplist\api\node_modules\typeorm\entity-manager\MongoEntityManager.js:60:54) at step (C:\Users\admin\Documents\projects\shoplist\api\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:143:27) at Object.next (C:\Users\admin\Documents\projects\shoplist\api\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:124:57) at fulfilled (C:\Users\admin\Documents\projects\shoplist\api\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:62) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)`

offices.controller.ts

```
@Get('/list')
findAll() {
  return this.officesService.findAll();
}
```

offices.service.ts

```
async findAll() {
  try {
    const offices = await this.officesRepository.find();

    return { success: true, message: 'Office successfully retrieved!', data: offices }
  } catch(e) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException({ success: false, error: e.message })
  }
}
```

I honestly don't know why it gives me error 500 with that message. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: the snippets that you shared are fine. Which line of them triggers that error?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've updated the question to include full stack trace

Comment: Are you using Mongo v4? If so, TypeORM doesn;t support it yet

Comment: I'm using mongo v4.4.6. It's strange because some of the http calls are working and I can see the values stored in my DB

Answer (score 1):

These errors seam like a mongodb version problem. If you are using mongodb > 3, Typeorm doesn't support yet. They have PR open at github --> https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7907

Answer (score 1):

It's issue of **mongodb** version with **typeorm**.

**typeorm** doesn't have support for >3 version yet.

Run this to resolve issue.

```
mongodb@3 @types/mongodb@3
```

Complete dependencies

```
npm install typeorm @nestjs/typeorm mongodb@3 @types/mongodb@3
```

Resolved same issue following this.